# Best tool to backup your firefox shortcuts

Tags: firefox, backup, shortcuts

I have lost my shortcuts a few times (from hard drive crashes).

Is there a good tool to back them up easily.  (I would prefer to not have to remember to do it.)

Backing them up to the internet would be a nice bonus, but it is not required for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla's Sync does it all! https://mozillalabs.com/sync/. It's a tool developed by the FireFox team themselves.

Features:
http://mozillalabs.com/sync/what-are-the-main-features-of-weave/

Answer (score 3):

If you mean bookmarks, Xmarks is a very good tool. It will sync/store them on a server, which will allow you to recover them in case of a crash or if you have multiple computers (desktop and laptop?) which you'd like to keep in sync. It can also sync across different browsers.